# Job to update all User to default country/region to USA Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to write a job that can be run to update all Users to default country/region to **USA**.

Here is the path [image]

System administration > Common > Users> All users.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
static void StackOverflow(Args _args)
{
    SysUserInfo         sysUserInfo;

    // Method 1
    ttsBegin;
    while select forUpdate sysUserInfo
    {
        SysUserInfo.DefaultCountryRegion = "USA";
        SysUserInfo.update();
    }
    ttsCommit;

    // Method 2
    update_recordSet sysUserInfo
        setting DefaultCountryRegion = "USA";

    info("End process");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Do not forget to mark as correct if it served you.